# ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE" in Docker-compose Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, create-table

I am trying to create two tables using docker-compose and a dockerfile with postgres sql. However, I get the following error.

`psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql:11: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE" postgres_1         | LINE 2: CREATE TABLE users`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I checked my sql query via `eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/` and it seems to be valid sql.

could it be the version of the postgres image I am using or something else? My dockerfiles look correct to me but please do let me know if I am missing something.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:latest

ADD /tables/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/
ADD /deploy_schemas.sql/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here is my `deploy_schemas.sql`

```
-- Deploy login and users tables

\i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql'
\i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/login.sql'
```

Here is my `users.sql`

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION


CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    entries BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);


COMMIT;
```

Here is my `login.sql`

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 



CREATE TABLE login (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    hash VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
); 




COMMIT;
```

and finally here is `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  #Backend API
  smart-brain-api:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /usr/src/test-api
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://admin:password@postgres:5432/test-api
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/test-api

  #Postgres
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: docker-test-api
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    build: ./postgres  
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you miss semicolon after `BEGIN TRANSACTION`