# PostgreSQL script - drop table if exist and create table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, docker

I have a problem with PostgreSQL script runing with docker-compose. I want to create only ONE table in PostgreSQL.

My script is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id      INT NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(255),
    surname VARCHAR(255),
    age     INT,
    email   VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);
```

Log from drocker-compose
Error message is:

```
postgres     | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres     |
postgres     |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres     |
postgres     | waiting for server to start....2022-07-11 08:39:50.970 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.4 (Debian 14.4-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres     | 2022-07-11 08:39:50.978 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres     | 2022-07-11 08:39:51.000 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-07-11 08:39:50 UTC
postgres     | 2022-07-11 08:39:51.008 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres     |  done
postgres     | server started
postgres     | CREATE DATABASE
postgres     |
postgres     |
postgres     | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-table-person.sql
postgres     | 2022-07-11 08:39:51.431 UTC [62] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE" at character 30
postgres     | 2022-07-11 08:39:51.431 UTC [62] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person
postgres     |  CREATE TABLE person
postgres     |  (
postgres     |      id      integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
postgres     |      name    VARCHAR(255),
postgres     |      surname VARCHAR(255),
postgres     |      age     integer,
postgres     |      email   VARCHAR(255)
postgres     |  );
postgres     | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-table-person.sql:9: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
postgres     | LINE 2: CREATE TABLE person
postgres     |         ^
postgres exited with code 3
```

and my Dockerfile for PostgreSQL is:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB testdatabase1

COPY create-table-person.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713670/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-create-in-docker-compose-postgres
Looks like a similar problem to the one I'm linking above

Comment: It works for me, when I try to reproduce it. Since it complains on line 2 of your script, I'm thinking that you might have saved the script with Windows CRLF line endings instead of Linux LF line endings.

Comment: Ok thanks. i dont know why, but its works.